# C'est complètement « nase/naze » : sens pour la « situation » ?

Tags: sens, orthographe, argot

> C'est complètement na[s|z]e !

Il me semble avoir déjà entendu cela. [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/nase/53829?q=naze#53474) traite du cas de l'*objet cassé* ou endommagé, ou de la personne, dans le sens d'*un peu fou ou ivre*, d'un registre populaire. En fait ça viendrait de *nazi* pour [*syphilis*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/naze/1) en argot et le TLFi suggère la comparaison avec [*loffe*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/loffe) (*arg*. nigaud, imbécile).

- Dans un cas où on ne discute ni de la personne ni d'un objet mais
  plutôt d'une *situation* ou d'un *évènement*, de quel sens s'agit-il
  précisément ?
- Y a-t-il une connotation particulière, une nuance avec le
  synonyme le plus usuel (lequel) ?
- Est-ce très argotique ou très quelque chose d'autre, et préfère-t-on une orthographe plutôt qu'une autre ?

Comment: À ne pas confondre avec _[barge](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/barge/8026), barjot_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionnaire culturel en langue française (sld Alain Rey) :

> **Nase ou Naze** adj. probablement dérivé (1917) de *nase*, *faux nase*, maladie de chevaux (morve) et des moutons, dérivé du radical latin de *nasus* « nez », ou de l'allemand *Nase* (nez). Le mot semble être apparu comme nom : *le nazi* (1878), *lazi* dès 1836 au sens de « syphilis ».*

Les deux orthographes, *nase* et *naze*,  sont employées, si les dictionnaires donnent *nase* en premier c'est probablement à cause de l'ordre alphabétique.

Pour un **objet** ou pour une **situation** le sens est le même, ça veut dire que c'est foutu, pourri.
*Foutu* et *pourri* sont uniquement familiers, *nase* est argotique.

Pour une **personne** ça veut dire qu'elle est très fatiguée, et parfois, selon le contexte, ivre. Là aussi l'emploi de *nase* est argotique.

<sup>*Il est probable (mais à confirmer) qu'il s'agisse de la [maladie de Borna](http://www.haras-nationaux.fr/information/accueil-equipaedia/maladies/maladies-infectieuses/maladie-de-borna.html), observée d'abord en Allemagne au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle et qui se transmet en particulier par les sécrétions nasales.</sup>

Comment: Pas vraiment, pour une personne "naze" n'est pas synonyme de "stupéfait" mais plutôt de "fatigué, dépassé". Une expression équivalente moins argotique serait "au bout du rouleau".

Comment: @AnneAunyme Je suis d'accord que *nase* n'est pas synonyme de « stupéfait » et d'ailleurs je ne l'ai jamais écrit. Historique des modifications disponible à tous.

Comment: @Laure: c'était une réponse à L'adit

Comment: Pour une personne, je pense que c'est également synonyme de "nul", "mauvais", voir "con". cf l'expression "être un (gros) naze".

Answer (score 3):

C'est un mot très familier, qui signifie de nos jours: *nul, raté, pourri*, que ce soit d'une personne, d'un objet, d'une situation, avec une connotation négative assez forte.

Un autre sens est *très usé / fatigué / fichu / cassé* : pour une personne ou un objet:

> Je suis (complètement) naze = Je suis totalement fatigué / fourbu.
>
> Le transistor est naze = le transistor est fichu.

Comme il est employé essentiellement à l'oral, à l'écrit les deux sont possibles.

L'origine vient [de nez](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/naze).

Comment: Plus 1 pour "fourbu" que je ne connaissais pas.